# access Sharepoint MOSS 2007 advanced search programmatically

Tags: 2007, search, development

In one of my custom master page template, I have a text box where a user can search various documents from different sources (which have already being crawled...), I want to programmatically provide the search string into advanced search feature and retrieve the results and display them in my custom view. How can I access advanced search using C# and carry out what I intended. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the search API directly using Query objects:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544561%28office.12%29.aspx

You have two options here:  FullTextSQLQuery which gives you a very robust set of options and the KeywordQuery which is a simplified search.  In both cases you can fully customize the display of the results.

If you generally like the normal SearchCoreResults Webpart it is also possible to override that and implement some customizations there.